# how to add number at the end of row in array numpy python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is any function that let me to add any number (e.g. "0") at end of every row in array.
Example:
I have two dimensional array:

```
ar=[[0,0,1],
[1,1,1],
[0,1,0]]
```

And I want add it to other 1-dimensional array, so I have:

```
 otherarray=numpy.array([],dtype=bool)
    otherarray=np.append(otherarray, ar)
```

Result:

```
 otherarray=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0]
```

And it works. But I need to add to every row of ar any number, e.g. 0 and get it as a result in otherarray (not modifying ar). 
Result I want:

```
[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

I am doing it using for loop (I'm putting every element to otherarray one-by-one) but now I'm asking: is any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a zero column to `ar` and then flatten it:

```
A = np.array(ar)    

np.hstack([A, np.zeros((A.shape[0], 1), dtype=A.dtype)]).ravel()
# array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!